# How to change the functionality of a key in android and symbian mobiles

Tags: android, java-me

I want to develop an application for blind using J2ME or Android. but i have few decision problems to make

1) Is it possible to change the functionality of a hard key in J2ME and Android

a) Totally like the home button can be changed to unlock the mobile like that

b) While program is running i.e An application is developed and during its usage the functionality can be modified.

2) Is it possible to add the audio feedback to the hard keys in J2ME or android

a) Totally like from the minute the mobile is switched on , whenever u press a button it will give its functionality in audio output.

b) While the program is running .i.e.An application is developed and during its usage the audio feedback can be added.

Please clear my doubts and help me in making decision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A touchscreen phone for blind people doesn't sound like a good idea to me :)

Android:

1 b) Without building your own custom rom no way to change the functionality of hard buttons globally. You are free to respond to buttons in your app as you like (except for the home button)

2 b) you can play any sounds while your app is running. But same problem here - you are resticted to inside your app.

Edit: Android has some features builtin:

http://eyes-free.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/android_access/index.html

Comment: Not 100% true, you can have your app start when Search is long-pressed.

Comment: thanks zapl thanks for ur answer, what if the mobile is not touchscreen a regular nokia smart phone[can be programmed using j2me]. whether above tasks or possible or not??